# Return value for BEGIN and INIT blocks?

Tags: perl

I'm browsing a (home written) Perl code base, and I see :

```
# BEGIN blocks :
BEGIN {
    ... #do stuff
    return 1;
}

#INIT blocks :
INIT {
    ... #do stuff
    return 1;
}
```

I couldn't find any info on the effect (or lack thereof) of the return value in a `BEGIN` or `INIT` block.

My question :
Does the return value of a `BEGIN` or `INIT` block have any influence on a module's compilation or execution ?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END

Comment: @teodozjan : I read that, I didn't see any mention of a return value from within a `BEGIN/INIT` block. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following test case :

```
#file TestModule.pm :
package TestModule;

BEGIN {
    print "BEGIN -- TestModule\n";
    return 0; # guessing a value which would mean "something went wrong"
}

INIT {
    print "INIT -- TestModule\n";
    return 0; # guessing a value which would mean "something went wrong"
}

1;

#file test.pl :

#!/usr/bin/perl

use TestModule;

print "Hello!\n";
```

The test.pl script happily runs :

```
$ perl test.pl
BEGIN -- TestModule
INIT -- TestModule
Hello !
```

which leads me to think the return value has no effect.

I would just like a stronger confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

This code blocks are executed by perl itself as something similar to subroutine so calling return just ends block execution and value is ignored. If you want to exit program with value use **exit**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;

BEGIN {exit 0}

say "start";
return 1;
```

Also there is another way to use `$?` but acording to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) it is working only for `END` blocks.

---

[ *OP comment* ]

@teodozjan rightly mentions that you can somehow interrupt the compiling (resp. start up) process by calling `exit` in the `BEGIN` (resp. `INIT`) block.

It should be noted that `exit 0` has quite a different effect than `return 0` though :

- `return 0` is Perl's syntax to say "exit from this function block and yield this value to your caller". It looks like the return value has no impact when you call it from a `BEGIN` or `INIT` block, but you still get the "stop function execution here" part, and Perl keeps running (the compilation / start up keeps on going).
- `exit 0` is Perl's syntax to say "halt the whole program now and yield this value as the process' exit status". It will work the same way from inside a `BEGIN` or `INIT` block : Perl will immediately stop compiling / executing your program, and the exit status (eg : `$?` in your shell) will be `0`.

Btw, `0` is the conventional exit status to say "everything went fine". If you want to signal an error, you should somehow `exit` with a non-zero status (or call `croak()` or `die()` : exit status will be 255).